# Database is not loading on device

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I made a application for Ipad and it was working fine on simultor but when it installed on device for testing, database is not loading the value.

I am developing for the ios 4.3 target and I add the sqlite database file into supporting file folder and in Appdelegate file in add this code:

### AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary  *)launchOptions
{
    [self createDatabaseExecutableFile];
}
```

and the method code is

```
// Creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory.
- (void) createDatabaseExecutableFile 
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL _success;
    NSFileManager* _fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError* _error;
    NSArray* _paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* _documentsDirectory = [_paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* _writableDBPath = [_documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turfnutritiontool_ver_two.db"];
    _success = [_fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_writableDBPath];
    if (_success)
        return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turfnutritiontool_ver_two.db"];
    _success = [_fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:_writableDBPath error:&_error];
    if (!_success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [_error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let me ask did you jail break your ios device ...

any ways debug line by line and check whether

your _writableDBPath    value and check whether db is on that location.

hope this will help you